# Prawn: Remove bottom padding for text_box

Tags: ruby, prawn

Here is an example where i draw text via text_box 3 times with different fonts.

```
anchor_point = {x: some_x, y: some_y}

pdf.fill_color '000000'
pdf.stroke_color 'FF0000'

pdf.font Consts::Fonts::VENEER do
  p1 = {at: [anchor_point[:x], anchor_point[:y] + 30], w: 60, h: 17}
  pdf.stroke_rectangle p1[:at], p1[:w], p1[:h]
  pdf.text_box 'TEXT',
               :at => p1[:at],
               :width => p1[:w],
               :height => p1[:h],
               :min_font_size => 1,
               :single_line => true,
               :overflow => :shrink_to_fit,
               :size => 17
end

pdf.font Consts::Fonts::ROBOTO do
  p1 = {at: [anchor_point[:x], anchor_point[:y]], w: 60, h: 17}
  pdf.stroke_rectangle p1[:at], p1[:w], p1[:h]
  pdf.text_box 'TEXT',
               :at => p1[:at],
               :width => p1[:w],
               :height => p1[:h],
               :min_font_size => 1,
               :single_line => true,
               :overflow => :shrink_to_fit,
               :size => 17
end

pdf.font Consts::Fonts::BEBAS do
  p1 = {at: [anchor_point[:x], anchor_point[:y] - 30], w: 60, h: 17}
  pdf.stroke_rectangle p1[:at], p1[:w], p1[:h]
  pdf.text_box 'TEXT',
               :at => p1[:at],
               :width => p1[:w],
               :height => p1[:h],
               :min_font_size => 1,
               :single_line => true,
               :overflow => :shrink_to_fit,
               :size => 17
end
```

And here is the result draw

[image]

I use `stroke_rectangle` to debug text_box bounds.

The question is:
How to remove bottom padding from text box. I tried change `:leading` in different ways but id does not have any effect.

Comment: Where do you get numbers like 30, 17 etc? Also, please use the example string having e.g. "g," “y,” and “q” letters in (like “Qygarq” instead of “TEXT”,) I believe that would answer your question.

Comment: @mudasobwa is correct fonts are usually measured from the top of the tallest character to bottom of the lowest character so what you are seeing is not padding but rather a line dictating where the lowest character in that font will reach. This allows for appropriate spacing between lines otherwise ascending and or descending characters would have a high livelihood of overlapping

Comment: ok. i got the point. If @mudasobwa create the answer i will accept it as solution.

Comment: Actually to make an answer I am to copy-paste the second comment, not mine. That said I’d appreciate @engineersmnky to make an answer :)